# How to change the font of a column header without CSS

Tags: java, javafx

I want to be able to change the font of a column header for JavaFX's TableView without using CSS. I've done a lot of searching online, and all of the solutions seem to only use CSS. The font I want to change it is a custom one, and loading custom fonts in CSS for JavaFX brings up an error that I can't seem to fix after searching tens of links.

The CSS approach I tried is

```
@font-face {
    font-family: '8bitoperator';
    src: url('assets/8bitoperator.ttf');
}

.table-view .column-header.foo .label {
    -fx-text-fill: white;
    -fx-font-size: 0.13%; /* arbitrary value */
    -fx-font-family: '8bitoperator';
}
```

Which runs into a `loadStylesheetUnPrivileged` error. All of my other stylings in my program has been through Javafx instead of CSS, so I would like to maintain that.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: hmm .. why talking (nearly exclusively) about css and using the css-tag when your goal is to __not__ use css? Please edit to cleanup the question and describe what you __do__ want to solve. Curious, is loading your custom font in code working? If so, it might be worth researching (including posting a focused question here, with a [mcve] :) to understand what's going wrong - going the css way is the most clean clean approach. Or - if successfully loaded - you can set the font style to the column, the header's skin (aka: TableColumnHeader) should be able to grab it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about your current issue with the stylesheet. But if you are looking for a way to update the fonts of the column header programatically, below is one approach. Having said that, there can be many other approaches.

The general idea is : the nodes you want, cannot be accessed through any general API. so We lookup for the nodes when the table view is fully rendered. The "needsLayout" property of a node will turn to false when it is fully rendered. So if you rely on that property and an extra property to not run multiple times,you can get your requirement using the "lookupAll" method.

```
import javafx.animation.AnimationTimer;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.scene.layout.Region;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean;

public class ColumnHeaderCustomFontDemo extends Application {
    boolean fontsLoaded = false;

    int i = 1;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        TableView<Person> tableView = new TableView<>();
        TableColumn<Person, String> fnCol = new TableColumn<>("First Name");
        fnCol.setPrefWidth(120);
        fnCol.setId("firstColumn");
        TableColumn<Person, String> lnCol = new TableColumn<>("Last Name");
        lnCol.setId("lastColumn");
        lnCol.setVisible(false);
        TableColumn<Person, String> cityCol = new TableColumn<>("City");
        cityCol.setId("cityColumn");
        tableView.getColumns().addAll(fnCol, lnCol, cityCol);

        tableView.needsLayoutProperty().addListener((obs, old, needsLayout) -> {
            if (!needsLayout) {
                AtomicBoolean updateLayout = new AtomicBoolean();
                tableView.lookupAll(".column-header").stream().map(node -> (Region) node).forEach(column -> {
                    if (column.getProperties().get("fontLoaded") == null) {
                        switch (column.getId()) {
                            case "firstColumn":
                                updateFont(column, "Calibri", 20);
                                updateLayout.set(true);
                                break;
                            case "lastColumn":
                                updateFont(column, "Verdana", 10);
                                updateLayout.set(true);
                                break;
                            case "newColumn":
                                updateFont(column, "Verdana", 25);
                                updateLayout.set(true);
                                break;
                        }
                        column.getProperties().put("fontLoaded", true);
                    }
                });
                if (updateLayout.get()) {
                    // A timer to execute only once in the next pulse.
                    new AnimationTimer(){
                        int count = 0;
                        @Override
                        public void handle(long now) {
                            if(count>1){
                               tableView.requestLayout();
                                stop();
                            }
                            count++;
                        }
                    }.start();
                }
            }
        });

        CheckBox showLastColumn = new CheckBox("Show LastName column");
        showLastColumn.selectedProperty().addListener((obs, old, val) -> lnCol.setVisible(val));
        Button addColumn = new Button("Add Column");
        addColumn.setOnAction(e -> {
            TableColumn<Person, String> newCol = new TableColumn<>("Column " + i++);
            newCol.setId("newColumn");
            tableView.getColumns().add(newCol);
        });
        VBox root = new VBox();
        root.setSpacing(10);
        root.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        root.getChildren().addAll(showLastColumn, addColumn, tableView);
        VBox.setVgrow(tableView, Priority.ALWAYS);

        Scene sc = new Scene(root, 500, 500);
        primaryStage.setScene(sc);
        primaryStage.setTitle("ColumnHeader Custom Font");
        primaryStage.show();

    }

    private void updateFont(Region column, String fontName, int fontSize) {
        column.lookupAll(".label").stream().map(node -> (Label) node).forEach(label -> label.setFont(new Font(fontName, fontSize)));
    }

    class Person {
        // TableView item
    }
}
```

Comment: yeah, possible :) Wondering, though: iff the problem is an inaccessible custom font, trying to set it wouldn't help, or would it? And you might consider mentioning that this doesn't cover added (either new or made visible again after hiding) columns. A custom TableColumnHeader would be nearer to the responsible party (unfortunately, would require lookup of the label as well)

Comment: It works! However, the resultant table seems to have a [visual glitch](https://imgur.com/0j16P1s), and when clicked a few times it readjusts itself to [this](https://imgur.com/gEJuBzP). Do you have any idea how to fix it?

Comment: I just noticed this if the resultant label size is bigger than the current column width. Looking for a proper fix.. will update when i get a solution.

Comment: I updated the demo to include a workaround for the glitch, by forcing the tableView requestLayout in the next pulse. And also updated the logic to handle the cases mentioned by @kleopatra

Comment: The update works! It does look a little weird since the size of the label being changed is really obvious. Thanks a million for your help though.

Comment: *cough .. this is doctoring on symptoms (of a problem that we can't solve, due to OP insisting on not giving enough details ;) at the wrong place. Loading a custom font and setting it to columns (be it via styleSheet, via tableColumn.setStyle or at a very last resort in a custom tableColumnHeader) __DOES__ work!

Comment: @kleopatra Yep! The CSS approach is definitely the best, and it was my bad to add the css tag when I was looking for an answer without it. Thanks for the overall clarification :)